# How do I deploy shiny application effectively without hitting Publish button?

Tags: r, shiny, rsconnect

When I try to deploy a Shiny application using the rsconnect in a script as below:

`rsconnect::deployApp("D:/InterestingTasks/meterreadings/meterreading/")` I get an error from shiny server stating:

**Error: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.**

The application makes use of two .rds datasets in the folder where the .rmd resides.
Any leads?

Comment: try adding the statement Loglevel = "verbose" to get a better understanding of what makes the error occur

Comment: __Error in rsconnect::deployApp("D:/InterestingTasks/meterreadings/meterreading/",  : 
  unused argument (Loglevel = "verbose")__

Comment: Not sure where to add the statement

Comment: That's on me I guess, the correct spelling is logLevel